# Format WOFF doesn't work on browser Chrome

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, typography

I have a strange problem. I have a font that only loads on Safari. The typography is in "WOFF" format. If anyone would have an idea.

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Moderat-Regular';
    src: url("fonts/Moderat-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/Moderat-Regular.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I also tried to load the typo in EOT, WOFT2. I have no results on Chrome, Firferox. It only works on Safari.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff the WOFF format is supported by Chrome, Firefox, Safari, ... Did you try to clear the cache in these browsers?

Comment: Hello, in first thank for your message. I have clear cache but again not result. I have also verified update Browser

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure to actually spend some time on reading ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask), since you're relying on the spare time of others; making sure they have all the details so they can give you a good answer is always appreciated. That said, you're loading literally the same source twice, so step one is to turn that into just once. On top of that, what does your dev console say in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge? "It doesn't work" is never true: the computer is doing exactly what you told it to, so include any console/network errors.